# How to fix error in dbconn file when upload php mysql project to free webhosting site?

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I've been trying to upload my PHP MySQL(in Dreamweaver) project to a free web-hosting site.

When I logged in, there is an error that appear in `dbconn.php` file.

**The error is shown below:**

[image]

**and here's the code in my `dbconn.php` file:**

```
<?php
/* php& mysqldb connection file */
$user = 1350048; //mysqlusername to db
$pass = "password"; //mysqlpassword to db
$host = "eskl.freeoda.com"; //server name or ipaddress
$dbname= 1350048; // db name in server freeoda
$dbconn= mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if(isset($dbconn)){
mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbconn) or die("<center>Error: " . mysql_error() . "</center>");
}
else{
echo "<center>Error: Could not connect to the database.</center>";
  }
?>
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can teach me how to solve this.. thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `$host = "127.0.0.1";`. And don't use `mysql_*` functions, they're deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. (Dreamweaver still exists??)

Comment: Yeah, you can't use mysql_connect etc, it's insecure and outdated. Try http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php instead.

Comment: @kerbholz people dont use dreamweaver anymore??? Ive been teaching myself php, and its is a project ive been doing on and off for couple of years. i didnt know it is outdated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kerbholz already stated, don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are really outdated.

Instead use mysqli:

```
$servername = "eskl.freeoda.com";
$username = "1350048";
$password = "password";
$database = "1350048";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

For your error it got mostly something to do your host doesn't allow remote connections. Try to change the serverhost to localhost or 127.0.0.1